# Django checkbox data navigation

Tags: django

I am using simple bootstrap form.

```
  

 <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Resource" id="defaultCheck1"  name="APP">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
           ABC
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="TC" id="defaultCheck2" name="APP" >
          <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck2">
            DEF
          </label>
          </div>
        
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="CM" id="defaultCheck3" name="APP">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck2">
            GHI
          </label>
        </div>
```

when i am submitting the form i am accessing it in view.py
below function is defined in view.py and in function getdata i am parsing the input submitted.

```
def getdata(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
                print(request.POST)
                print(request.POST['APP'])  
                app=request.POST['APP']
                print(app)
```

in this code i am using post to check the request type if it is true i am accessing request object and parsing it.

```
      output of above is :
        <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['cdcdcdcdcd'],'APP': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']}>
         RPL
         RPL
```

Comment: What's your issue exactly?

Comment: i am not getting array as a result so not able to iterate .

Comment: print(request.POST['APP']) i am expecting array as a result .